# How to use axios for accessing external API server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

Basically, i have to access into two server (i.e bridging communication between this two server)

1. internal server (local server in dev)
2. external server which is the 3rd party/partner

first as a test, I build a log in function which is success in accessing API external server if executed via terminal, but failed when i integrated into reactjs

the similar log in function into local server is running well.

here is my code

1. Stand alone/terminal

```
    const axios = require('axios')

    const Con = async () => {
    try {
        console.log('No Error  here')
        const response = await axios
        .post('https://xyz/pcs/api/account/auth',
        {
          "userID": "me",
          "password": "123"
        }
        )
        console.log('You are connected to System')
        console.log('status : ' + response.status)
        console.log('token : ' + response.data.token);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Failed to connect')
    }
    }
    Con()
```

here the result

```
    No Error  here
    You are connected to  System
    status : 200
    token :  xyz123
```

2. When integrated into react

```
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
    import React from 'react'
    const axios = require('axios')


    function Connect() {

    const handleClick = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios
                .post('https://xyz/pcs/api/account/auth', {
                    "userID": "me",
                    "password": "123"
                })
                console.log('You are connected to System')
                console.log('status : ' + response.status)
                console.log('token : ' + response.data.token);
    
        } catch (error) {console.log('Failed to connect')
                  
        }
      };

    return (
        <Button variant='info' onClick={handleClick} className='text-white'>
            Connect to system
        </Button>
   )
   }

  export default Connect
```

and result as console log

`Failed to connect`

3. And this is axios post method for internal server Log in

```
    import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Container, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

    const today = new Date()

    function Login() {

    const idRef = useRef()
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
    user_name: "",
    password: "",
    showPass: false,
    });
    const [ message, setMessage ] = useState('')
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const Auth = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    try {
        await axios
            .post('http://localhost:3500/login', {
                user_name: values.user_name,
                password: values.password
            })
            navigate('/dashboard')

    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            setMessage(error.response.data.message)
            console.log(error.response.data.message)
            return navigate('/')  
        }            
    }
   };

   return (
    <Container className="align-items-center d-flex border-none position-absolute top-0 end-0 bg-rose-600  text-white" style={{ height: '100vh', width : '300px' }}>
      <Form onSubmit={Auth} className="w-100">
        <Form.Group>
          
          <p className="text-white text-xs italic text-center">{message}</p><br/><hr/><br/>
          
          <Form.Label>User Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text"
            ref={idRef} required
            placeholder='User name'
            
            onChange={(e) => setValues({ ...values, user_name: e.target.value })}
          />
          
          <p className="text-white text-xs italic">Fill in a user name</p>

          <Form.Label className='mt-4'> Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="password"
            ref={idRef} required
            placeholder='Password'
            
            onChange={(e) => setValues({ ...values, password: e.target.value })}
          />
          <p className="text-white text-xs italic">Fill in a password</p>
        </Form.Group>
        <br/><hr/>
        <Button type="submit" className="mt-4 border-white bg-rose-700  w-2/3 mx-auto">Login</Button>
        <p className="text-center text-white text-xs pb-6 mt-2">
        &copy;  <span>2023 - {today.getFullYear()} </span>
        Me Corp. All rights reserved.
      </p> 
  
      </Form>
      
    </Container>
    )
    }

    export default Login
```

result : success with access and refresh token

Comment: React is ran on browser not NodeJS. it works differently. in browser, it got CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) and CSP (Content Security Policies). the one you got problem is probably CORS. the API you are accessing preventing you to connect directly when the request is from different domain (your domain is different with the API or not an allowed domain by the API). it is security design. solution? create a backend that bridge it between your website and the API you are using.

Comment: TypeError: axios.post is not a function
    handleClick Connect.jsx:12
    React 23
        callCallback....
​

Comment: I think it's a problem on ES Module Interop, but I'm not quite sure. try to use `import { default as axios } from 'axios';` instead

Comment: if the problem is CORS blocked, then create a REST API in your internal server, which in the server do the request to the API like how you do it in NodeJS. so, your frontend can easily access it via your internal server. or request to the API creator to make Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to accepting your website domain.

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xyz/pcs/api/account/auth. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 204. ...hm i check my network (cellular wifi) : private :(

Comment: oh by that way? ok i will figure it out and try it, i will give you an update, thank you @nouvist